# run 2 function after complete eachother

Tags: javascript, function, timer

i have 2 function that i want to run like this
when page load for first time after 30 min run `t_exit`
after `t_exit` completes, wait for 30 min and run `t_recon`
again after 30min run exit wait 30min run `t_recon`
and this loop will continue.

how can i make that happen ?
This is my code

```
function t_recon() {
   //reconnect
}

function t_exit() {
   //exit
  setTimeout(t_recon, 1800000);
}

setTimeout(t_exit, 1800000);
```

what i tried

`setInterval` did not work because it runs them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `setTimeout()` inside each function. When the timeout expires, it calls the other function.

Following code snippet calls each function with a delay of 5 seconds between function calls.

```js
let waitTime = 5000;

function t_recon() {
  console.log('t_recon function ran');
  setTimeout(t_exit, waitTime);
}

function t_exit() {
  console.log('t_exit function ran');
  setTimeout(t_recon, waitTime);
}


setTimeout(t_exit, waitTime);
```

Comment: thanks its worked..but an other question i have what if i want to run t_exit after 30min and then wait for 10min and run t_recon ?

Comment: just change the number of milliseconds in `setTimeout` function that is inside `t_exit` function